# Eloquent JavaScript 2nd Edition recursion exercise solution

Tags: javascript, recursion

I attempted to solve the recursion exercise of the online book [eloquentjavascript 2nd edition](http://eloquentjavascript.net//2nd_edition/preview/03_functions.html#p_iDq2OgBOGw):

Here is what the question states:

> We’ve seen that % (the remainder operator) can be used to test whether
>   a number is even or odd by using % 2 to check if it’s divisible by
>   two. Here’s another way to define whether a (positive, whole) number
>   is even or odd:
>
> - Zero is even.
> - One is odd.
> - For any other number N, its evenness is the same as N - 2.
>
> Define a recursive function isEven corresponding to this description.
>   The function should accept a number parameter and return a boolean.
>
> Test it out on 50 and 75. See how it behaves on -1. Why? Can you think
>   of a way to fix this?

Here is what I have attempted and it works:

```
function isEven(number) {
    if (number == 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return (-number % 2 == 0) ? true : false;
    }
    return isEven(number - 2);
}

console.log(isEven(-1));
```

But, it seems to be a wrong answer because as I understood the author wants me to use - 2 method. I am wondering if this is indeed the correct answer or if it is wrong could someone point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 12):

I think the reason you are getting confused is because you're not understanding how recursion works. The reason it is n-2 is, it is taking the number and subtracting 2 until it is either a zero or one. Therefore giving us a true or false.

Hope that helps. Read over how the process of recursion works.

Answer (score 7):

The alternative solution that doesn't use the modulos operator `%` or any other built in functions in JavaScript is provided below. This solution instead relies on using another recursion to change negative value of the number.

```
function isEven(number) {
    if (number < 0) {
        return isEven(-number);
    } else if (number == 1) {
        return false;
    } else if  (number == 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return isEven(number - 2);
    }
}

console.log(isEven(50)); // true
console.log(isEven(75)); // false
console.log(isEven(-1)); // false
```

Comment: I've read over recursion in this book over and over, looked at your code, and it still just makes zero sense to me. Why are we calling isEven(number - 2)? What is that doing?

Comment: "For any other number N, its evenness is the same as N - 2."

Comment: using ternary operator - function isEven (x) {
return x > 1 ? isEven(x-2) : x===1 ? false : x===0? true: isEven (-x);
}

Answer (score 5):

We call isEven(number -2) to go back to the top of the function with the number that was inputed intially but 2 less than before and it will keep doing that until the number is 1 or 0 and then it will be able to return the boolean true or false (even or odd).

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is to create an isEven function without using a mod/%/remainder operation

```
function isEven(number) {
  if (number < 0) {
    number = Math.abs(number);
  }
  if (number===0) {
    return true;
  }
  if (number===1) {
    return false;
  }
  else {
    number = number - 2;
    return isEven(number);
  }

}
```

I guess it is important to add to this

1. it doesn't handle strings
2. it doesn't handle floats
3. don't put this into a production application

Comment: I think so too, my answer felt like I didn't complete the task :(

Comment: console.log(isEven(-3)); results it too much recursion error.

Comment: this wasn't meant to be production code, but instead an idea of what the exercise was about. I don't think a down vote was warranted, but what do I know...

Comment: You can use `Math.abs` to handle negative numbers

Comment: @levi - was just updating it

Answer (score 2):

```
function isEven(n) {
 n = Math.abs(n);
  if (n==0) 
    return true;
  else if (n==1)
    return false;
  else 
    return isEven(n-2);
}

console.log(isEven(-50)); // → true
console.log(isEven(75)); // → false
console.log(isEven(-75)); // → false
console.log(isEven(-1)); // → false
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please add a little explanation on why this code works.

Answer (score 1):

```
var isEven = function(n) {
  // Get the absolute value of the number
  // so we don't have to bother with negatives
  n = Math.abs(n);

  // We know that if we subtract 2 from our number
  // until it is equal to zero, our number was even
  // If our number isn't zero, this statement will be skipped
  if(n === 0) return true;

  // We know that if we subtract 2 from our number
  // and it reaches a value of 1, it isn't even
  // If our number isn't 1, this statement will be skipped
  if(n === 1) return false;

  // We subtract 2 from our original number and pass it
  // back in to this function to check it over and over again
  // until one of the conditions is met and the function can
  // return a result
  return isEven(n - 2);
}

// We test our function here
console.log(isEven(-21));
```

This is the leanest method I could come up with. Notice we call our isEven function from within itself and pass in the value of n - 2. This will constantly subtract 2 from our number and check to see if it is equal to 0 or 1 until we get a proper result and return the corresponding boolean.

I hope this clears things up a little.

Answer (score 1):

How about the below code? Seems to work for me.

```
/*if > 1 keep looking, otherwise return reverse boolean value. 
If negative value, inverse, to answer the last part of the question... 
Also needed to use parseInt as the text value I used, 
was considered a string value!
This being a recursive function which really isn't necessary, 
means that in javascript we will get a 
stack size exceeded error when the number becomes too large.*/

function isEven(x) {
    return (x>1)?isEven(x-2):(x>=0)?!x:isEven(-x);
}
```

Comment: It is probably not helpful for someone who has trouble with basic concepts like recursion to give code-golf solutions.

Answer (score 1):

The book wants the following console.log outputs for such values

```
console.log(isEven(50));
// → true
console.log(isEven(75));
// → false
console.log(isEven(-2));
// → ??
```

The hint says "When given a negative number, the function will recurse again and again, passing itself an ever more negative number, thus getting further and further away from returning a result. It will eventually run out of stack space and abort." So I'm not sure if what I got represents that but my code and console.log outputs is shown below:

````
   let isEven = function(num) {
         if (num ===0) {
             return true
         } else if (num===1){
             return false
         } else {
             return isEven(num-2)
         }
    }    

console.log(isEven(50));
// → true
console.log(isEven(75));
// → false
console.log(isEven(-2));
// → RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded (line 3 in function isEven)```
````

Answer (score 0):

The question requires that you don't' not to use the modulus operator (%).

```
// Your code here.
var isEven = function(a){
  if (a == 0){ //case 1 : zero is even
    return true;
  }
  else if(a == 1){ //case 2: one is odd 
    return false;
  }
    else {
      return isEven(Math.abs(a-2)); //solves case 3 (negative numbers)
    }
}

console.log(isEven(50));
// → true
console.log(isEven(75));
// → false
console.log(isEven(-1));
// → ?? ....false
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the ["correct"](http://eloquentjavascript.net/code/#3.2) answer from the website. I say "correct" in quotes because I don't understand the 2nd 'else if' statement's `return isEven(-n)`. Why did the author include the option to turn `n` into a positive number?

```
function isEven(n) {
  if (n == 0)
    return true;
  else if (n == 1)
    return false;
  else if (n < 0)
    return isEven(-n);
  else
    return isEven(n - 2);
}
```

Anyways, thought I'd share since I didn't see anybody post THIS answer.

Comment: Rather than rely on an external method `Math.abs(number)` as others have posted here in their answers, doing it this way that the author chose keeps the solution entirely self-contained. The whole function can be read as _"if the number is zero it is even; if the number is one it is odd; if the number is negative its even-ness is the even-ness of its positive value; otherwise its even-ness is the same as the number minus two"_ — this is almost exactly the same as the way the problem was stated in the exercise.

Comment: This answer is functionally equal to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23256734/240443) by user2578173 (disregarding minor speed differences due to reordering of if clauses).

Answer (score 0):

```
//define recursive function isEven takes a positive whole number
//returns true if even
function isEven(x) {
  //define innner function to loop over value
  function find(current) {
    //check if value == 0, return true
    if (current == 0) { 
      return true
    //check if value == 1 return false
     } else if (current == 1)  {
        return false
    //loop over value, subtracting 2 each time until either 0 or 1
    //which returns the approriate true/false value based on evenness
     } else {
     console.log(current)
     return find(current -2)
    }
  }
    return find(x)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the number is **1** or **-1** so **ODD**, the function returns **false**,
If the number is **0** so **EVEN**, it returns **true**,
*If then number nor 1,-1 nor 0 we have to first check if the number is positive or negative,*
If the number is **negative** and **less than -1** we **call the function again** but **increase the number by 2** until we get -1 or 0;
If the number is **positive** and **greater than 1** we **call the function again** but **decrease the number by 2** until we get 1 or 0;
So for example, the number is **5** ->
*it`s positive and greater than 1 so call the function over and over again and decrease the number by 2 until the result will be 0 or 1:*
**5->3->1  //->false**

```
    function isEven(num) {
    if (num == 1 || num == -1) {
        return false;
    } else if (num == 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        if (num < -1) {
            return isEven(num + 2);
        } else {
            return isEven(num - 2);
        }
    }
}
```

Test result:

```
console.log(`-35 is even: ${isEven(-35)}`); //-> false
console.log(`-1 is even: ${isEven(-1)}`);  //-> false
console.log(`0 is even: ${isEven(0)}`);  //-> true
console.log(`32 is even: ${isEven(32)}`);  //-> true
```

Comment: It might be  easier to handle negative numbers with `if (num < 0) {return isEven(- num)}`

Answer (score 0):

I see quite a few examples above using math functions and modulo operator. But I guess the author expects a simple recursive function to make the reader understand the functioning of the same and how if not properly defined it can lead to repetitive function calls and eventually lead to overflow of stack. I believe this code below can help you understand:

```js
function isEven(n){
  if(n==0){
    return true;
  } else if(n==1){
    return false;
  } else {
    return isEven(n-2);
  }
}
console.log(isEven(50));
console.log(isEven(75));
console.log(isEven(-1));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function isEven(num){
 if(num %2 == 0) {
 return true;
} else {
  return false;
 }
}

console.log(isEven(50));
// → true

console.log(isEven(75));
// → false

console.log(isEven(-1));
// → ??
```

Comment: Welcome to _StackOverflow_, you might want to read [how to post an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) before doing so. Give a bit of context explaining why you posted that code and what does it do. Also consider taking the time to format your answer to be easily understood by readers.

Comment: Please give some explanation about your solution :)

Comment: Your solution is doing exactly what the problem statement said _**not**_ to do. It is looking for "another way to define whether a positive whole number is even or odd" ... a way _**other** than_ using the remainder `%` operator.

Answer (score -2):

```
function isEven(number) {
    while(number>= -1)
    {   
        return isEven(number-2) == 0 && number>-1 ? true : false;
    }
}
console.log(isEven(-1));
```

Comment: Why the completely useless `while` loop? Why the useless ternary operator?

Comment: while loop is to control recursion and ternary operator is a check for even and odd

Comment: How does that loop control the recursion if you do not change the value assigned to `number`?

Answer (score -2):

I hope this helps:

```
const evenOrOdd = (N) => {
    if (Math.abs(N) === 0) {
        return console.log('Even');
    } else if (Math.abs(N) === 1) {
        return console.log('Odd');
    }
    evenOrOdd(Math.abs(N) - 2);
};
```

[Google Chrome Console code results:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DO5Vf.png)

It utilizes all three given arguments on the problem. It can handle negative integers. It does not use the modulo operator. Lastly, I wasn't able to see any code snippet similar to what I provided thus I am enticed to share what I can.

Comment: Why should we do that? Do you have any question about your code? Then please open a new question - don't post a question in the answer section

Comment: Hello Nico, I think I confused you. I am actually suggesting an answer to the initial question provided above.

Comment: What the function 'evenOrdOdd' does is it is recursing itself by repeatedly subtracting 2 to the 'N' (inputted number) until it arrives to a number equal to either 0 or 1. Finally, a corresponding console.log value ('Even' or 'Odd') will appear depending on the ending number (0 or 1).

Comment: And why should one use a completely new block of code? Why not help the OP find the error in its own code?

Comment: Of course you can - but then you should highlight what makes your code better than all other solutions. What does it contain that is "improved" over any other solution?

Comment: It utilizes all three given arguments on the problem. It can handle negative integers. It does not use the modulo operator. Lastly, I wasn't able to see any code snippet similar to what I provided thus I am enticed to share what I can.

Comment: So, after all: there is nothing bad in your code. But you absolutely need to add all that information about why your code is "improved" over others to the answer itself, not to the comment section

Comment: I will take note of that. Thank you.

Comment: The specification called for a boolean predicate function which this isn't.